# Dot Comma Minus Plus in GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I am trying to use the GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey) function, but i have a little problem :
It works fine for letters, numbers and keys (like Enter or Space), but the Function is not working when I try to use for example the comma ",".

```
    #include <myHead.h>

    int main()
    {
    char i = 44;

        while(1)
        {
            Sleep(5);
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(i)<0)
            {
                cout << "Got it!";
            }
        }

    }
```

I should add that i am using a Windows 7 Lap Top

Comment: 44 is the VK code for the print screen key...

Comment: i looked it up in the ascii table, and 44 is "," ?

Comment: VK code != ASCII code (what would the code for print screen be then?) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: but why is the ascii code working with numbers and letters?

Comment: Because they purposefully made those the same as the ASCII codes.

Comment: okay I will change my whole code then and let you know if it worked :-)

Comment: so now I changed it and the "," i wanted is a ¼ ?

Comment: I presume you're printing the VK code as a character. Again, they're completely different topics. You might try [`ToAscii`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646316(v=vs.85).aspx) to pull out the ASCII character.

Comment: okay, so how can i display the int i = 0x30 ?

Comment: To get a '0', `ToAscii` works. To get "0x30", `std::hex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [VkKeyScanEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646332.aspx) function to know the VK code for a given character.

If your are just interested by the user pressing the corresponding key on the keyboard, that should do the trick. But, if you want to distinguish from shifted/non shifted, and or usage of ALT (as the euro symbol on a french keyboard, Alt+E), things are more complicated.

Simple example:

```
SHORT sRet = VkKeyScanEx( ',', 0 );
BYTE vk = LOBYTE( sRet );
```

On my laptop, vk is 188 (0xBC) and GetAsyncKeyState(188) return <0 when I hit my ',' keyboard key (french keyboard)

(yes, VK_OEM_COMMA is 0xBC)

Comment: @HansPeter Hum... Accept an answer and Upvote an answer are two different things.